# Is there a best practice for throttling service calls to Windows services?

Tags: c#, windows, security, windows-services

My team ships a client API that allows applications to communicate with our Windows service. There is a concern that malicious apps could possibly flood our service with requests, so we want to put in some throttling logic on the client API to prevent DOS attacks like this.

Is there a best practice for implementing throttling logic for Windows services? All I can find online is throttling for web (which makes sense). I imagine the same ideas would apply, but I am wondering if there is an established mechanism to do this when it's all on the local system.

Answer (score 0):

You might find an open source project like [TokenBucket](https://github.com/esendex/TokenBucket) to be suitable to implement this.

See WikiPedia for a discussion on [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) algorithms in general.

For your application you may need to consider how to prevent multiple instances of your API from being called from the same machine, same process or multiple threads and that might affect how you implement this.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, but thanks for the leads.